# rsync Only Latest Files Sync

Tags: rsync

I am having scenario, the following directory contain files.

Name        Modiffiled Date
File1.bak   18 Oct 2015 
File2.bak   17 Oct 2015
File3.bak   16 Oct 2015

The above files in GB's and want to sync only two latest files on Dest Dir, so, is there any way do this instead of moving / copying files to separate folder?

Thanks

Rashid

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answer:http://superuser.com/questions/297342/rsync-files-newer-than-1-week - you should be able to adapt it to your jedes.

Comment: Hi, looks same but I need bit explanation and how can I fit directors e.g source /u01/dir1 and detestation e.g /u01/dri2 in this example:   " rsync -RDa0P \
    --files-from=<(find sourcedir/./ -mtime -7 -print0) \
    . user@B:targetdir/ "

Comment: Just replace `sourcedir/` and `targetdir/`.

Comment: Thanks, will check and update